# R interface for Stanford Parser

Tags: r, stanford-nlp

Is there a package that ports Stanford parser in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/helloJavaWorld/vignettes/helloJavaWorld.pdf will show you how to leverage the rJava package and some minimal Java code to use external Java packages.

The Stanford NLP parsers have API documentation which you could use to create a wrapper in Java.

I am trying to use the NLP parsers from Stanford from R and once I have usable code, I'll b glad to share it with you here.

Comment: Thanks Harsh!!! I will be happy to get some help from you. I also found alternate way, which I can share.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing on CRAN.  [RSeek returns nothing](http://www.rseek.org/?cx=010923144343702598753:boaz1reyxd4&q=%22Stanford+parser%22&sa=Search&cof=FORID:11&siteurl=www.rseek.org/%3Fcx%3D010923144343702598753%253Aboaz1reyxd4%26q%3DStanford%2Bparser%26cof%3DFORID%253A11).  And [the NLP view on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html) doesn't show it.

Comment: Thanks Shane, I also did some searching on the same. Are you aware of any other dependency parsers in R?